# java LocalDate Datatype, if I have to enter parameters from a 2D array into LocalDate,it's throwing exceptions

Tags: java, arrays, types

[image: it's giving a DateTimeException.All the input values are integers.]
It's giving a `DateTimeException`. All the input values are integers. If inputting the parameters of LocalDate from 2D array, it's throwing exceptions. Why?

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
int[][] arr=new int[3][2];
for(int j=0;j<2;j++){
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        while(sc.hasNext()){
            arr[i][j]=sc.nextInt();
            // System.out.println(arr[i][j]);
        }   
        LocalDate ret1=LocalDate.of(arr[2][j],arr[1][j],arr[0][j]);
        System.out.println(ret1);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please show your values of arr[2][j],arr[1][j],arr[0][j] and provide the exception raised.

Comment: Uncomment that `System.out.println(arr[i][j])` and you will know.

Comment: Somehow, I am getting java.time.DateTimeException. All my inputs are integral values.The values are getting stored in the array but giving exceptions when passed into LocalDate. @adam

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Comment: I did that too but still am not able to understand the problem. @joe

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int[][] arr = new int[3][2];
for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        arr[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
        // System.out.println(arr[i][j]);
    }
    LocalDate ret1 = LocalDate.of(arr[2][j], arr[1][j], arr[0][j]);
    System.out.println(ret1);
}
```

You do not need the `sc.hasNext()` method in combination with `System.in`. Furthermore you should create the LocalDate object after assigning each required value to your array. (So in the first for-loop).

If you want to enter the whole date in one single line I'd rather scan the whole line, split it and parse the remaining strings to integers:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int[][] arr = new int[2][3];
for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
    String[] line = scan.nextLine().split("\\D+");    // Splits the line when there is at least one non-digit. (So you could also write something like '1 day 8th month _1776_', it just has to be in this particular order.)
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        arr[j][i] = Integer.parseInt(line[i]);
    }
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(arr[j][2], arr[j][1], arr[j][0]);
    System.out.println(date);
}
```